# Function args declared as consts became non constant with definition

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, constants

Code

```
class A
{
 public:
    void f(const int i);
};
void A::f(int i)
{
    std::cout<<++i<<std::endl;
}
int main()
{
   A a;
   a.f(1);
}
```

Why compiler does not give an error in this case ? Why the definition overrides the constant argument ?
Also, when the argument is of type `reference (&)` the compiler throws error but why not in this case ?

Is there any compiler flag to enable warning on these mentioned cases ?

I am interested more from compiler error POV. Because one can easily put declaration (const) and definition(non-constant) differently and still compiler accepts it. If a mistake can be made it will eventually be made. Why can't compiler complain when there is such difference present.

Comment: When you change to reference it will fail to compile: https://ideone.com/EwaVvR

Comment: Sitesh: that is *top-level* const which can be ignored in the definition.

Answer (score 5):

From *11.3.5 Functions [dcl.fct]*:

> 5. A single name can be used for several different functions in a single
>      scope; this is function overloading (Clause 16). All declarations for
>      a function shall agree exactly in both the return type and the
>      parameter-typelist. The type of a function is determined using the
>      following rules. The type of each parameter (including function
>      parameter packs) is determined from its own decl-specifier-seq and
>      declarator. After determining the type of each parameter, any
>      parameter of type “array of T” or of function type T is adjusted to be
>      “pointer to T”. *After producing the list of parameter types, any
>      **top-level cv-qualifiers** modifying a parameter type are deleted when
>      forming the function type*. The resulting list of transformed parameter
>      types and the presence or absence of the ellipsis or a function
>      parameter pack is the function’s parameter-type-list.

Basically, it means, that `const int` and `int` are interchangeable in the context of your question.

On the other hand, if you add a reference, like `const int&`, `const` is not a top level cv-qualifier anymore (it marks the referenced value as `const`), so the compiler complains.

Usually, `const` is added to the definition in order to emphasise that the parameter is not changed inside the function body.

Comment: Emphasize and, more importantly, enforce.

Comment: I am interested more from compiler error POV. Because one can easily put declaration (const) and definition(non-constant) differently  and still compiler accepts it. If a mistake can be made it will eventually be made. Why can't compiler complain when there is such difference present.

Answer (score 3):

The function declaration

```
void f(const T arg);
```

is same as

```
void f(T arg);
```

However,

```
void f(const T& arg);
```

is not the same as

```
void f(T& arg);
```

and

```
void f(const T* arg);
```

is not the same as

```
void f(T* arg);
```

---

```
void f(const T arg);
void f(T arg);
```

are same because top-level cv-qualifiers are removed for function resolution purposes. There, the `const`-ness is applied to the top-level type, `T`.

OTOH,

```
void f(const T& arg);
void f(T& arg);
```

are not same since the `const`-ness is applied to the object being referred to by the reference `arg`, not to `arg` itself which is just a *top-level* thing.

Comment: Mention *top-level* const-ness to explain it. Not all const-ness are same in C++.

Comment: @Nawaz, I don't follow your drift. How would top-level const-ness affect the answer?

Comment: `const T arg` and `T arg` are equivalent because `const T arg` has top-level const, while `const T * arg` has not, though `T * const` is equivalent to `T *`, again because `T * const` has top-level const, hence can be ignored in the definition.

Comment: `void f(const T arg);` is not the "same" that `void f(T arg);` !

Comment: @Stargateur: As long as `T` is a value type, it *is* the same in this context. The `const` tells the *caller* that his argument won't be changed by `f()`. As the parameter is passed by value anyway, the contract indicated by the `f( const T arg )` declaration is honored even by `f( T arg )` for value types. Check Edgar's answer (or the linked dupe) for the standard legalese.

Comment: @RSahu: Have edited your post. Feel free to rollback if it's not good enough.

Comment: @DevSolar it's the same in all cases of `T`

Comment: @Nawaz, not a problem. Thanks for the edit.